# Separating grouped databses on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Someone at my work added a couple of WordPress installs to subdomains on our webs hosting space, and the databases for the WordPress installs have grouped together with our main websites database, which is a Drupal website. So - when our website is looking for it's db it can't find it because it's inside a group of databases.
How do I ungroup them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if anyone is as dopey as me, but I figured I'd post this, just in case it helps anyone at any time.
It wasn't the grouping of the databases, it was that the user for the databases had had the privileges removed. I'd seen this in an error message too, but when I was trying to figure out how to ungroup the databases, I noticed (in cPanel - MySQL Databases) that the user had no privileges, so I added them back in and the website came straight back online.